# linux kernel alignment exception error after upgrading gcc version

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using `yocto jethro` to build my bespoke linux distro for a `OMAP3630` processor. I have a precompiled linaro toolchain version `gcc-4.7.3` and my kernel is version `3.2`. I am trying to upgrade my cross compiler to `gcc-4.8.4` (using the gcc version provided by yocto, not linaro).

Everything seems to compile correctly, but when I run the kernel, I get the following alignment exception error message:

```
[    0.516387] Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x001) at 0x0073656b
[    0.523193] Internal error: : 1 [#1] PREEMPT
[    0.527679] Modules linked in:
[    0.530914] CPU: 0    Tainted: G        W     (3.2.0-rc1 #6)
[    0.536834] PC is at rb_next+0x24/0x68
[    0.540771] LR is at sysfs_remove_dir+0x84/0xcc
[    0.545532] pc : [<c0194948>]    lr : [<c0130084>]    psr: 20000013
[    0.545532] sp : cf837f70  ip : 22222222  fp : 00000000
[    0.557525] r10: 00000000  r9 : c04c95e0  r8 : 00000000
[    0.562988] r7 : c04c9724  r6 : cf837f40  r5 : fffffffe  r4 : cf801cc0
[    0.569793] r3 : 69766564  r2 : 00736563  r1 : 22222222  r0 : cf801cc0
[    0.576629] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[    0.584228] Control: 10c5387f  Table: 80004019  DAC: 00000015
[    0.590240] Process swapper (pid: 1, stack limit = 0xcf8362f0)
[    0.596313] Stack: (0xcf837f70 to 0xcf838000)
[    0.600891] 7f60:                                     cf812310 00000000 c04c95e8 fffffffe
[    0.609405] 7f80: 00000000 c01900a4 c04c95e8 c01d7ae4 00000000 00000000 c04c95e0 ffff6a0e
[    0.617919] 7fa0: 00000000 c01e40b8 00000000 c0497aa4 00007fb0 c000f1b8 00000013 00000000
[    0.626434] 7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0475784 c0497aa4 c0475818 cf80f8c0 c045d80c
[    0.634948] 7fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c045d78c c000f1b8 2b22d90f 18552020
[    0.643463] [<c0194948>] (rb_next+0x24/0x68) from [<c0130084>] (sysfs_remove_dir+0x84/0xcc)
[    0.652160] [<c0130084>] (sysfs_remove_dir+0x84/0xcc) from [<c01900a4>] (kobject_del+0x10/0x38)
[    0.661224] [<c01900a4>] (kobject_del+0x10/0x38) from [<c01d7ae4>] (device_add+0x12c/0x59c)
[    0.669921] [<c01d7ae4>] (device_add+0x12c/0x59c) from [<c0475784>] (platform_bus_init+0x14/0x4c)
[    0.679168] [<c0475784>] (platform_bus_init+0x14/0x4c) from [<c0475818>] (driver_init+0x1c/0x28)
[    0.688293] [<c0475818>] (driver_init+0x1c/0x28) from [<c045d80c>] (kernel_init+0x80/0x120)
[    0.696990] [<c045d80c>] (kernel_init+0x80/0x120) from [<c000f1b8>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[    0.706146] Code: e3520000 1a000001 ea000005 e1a02003 (e5923008) 
[    0.712524] ---[ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed22 ]---
[    0.717407] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

I had a similar issue before with `gcc-4.7.3`, that I solved adding `-mno-unaligned-access` to `EXTRA_CFLAGS` when compiling the kernel, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem with `gcc-4.8.4`. I have also compared gcc commands when compiling the kernel with one version and the other and they are identical. I have briefly tested `gcc-4.9` as well with similar results. This makes me think that yocto gcc could be configured incorrectly, but no idea of what specific config value could be causing this.

Some info about my `gcc-4.7.3`:

```
$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/../poky/external-precompiled-toolchain/toolchains/arm-linaro-5//bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/alima/projects/yocto/poky/external-precompiled-toolchain/toolchains/Thumb2_linaro-4.7-2012.11_eglibc-2.16/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /tmp/build/src/gcc-linaro-4.7-2012.11/configure --build=x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/toolchains/arm-linaro-5 --with-sysroot=/opt/toolchains/arm-linaro-5/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=neon --with-float=hard --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG hg+default-2af20cfd210b - arm-linaro-4' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --with-gmp=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-mpfr=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-mpc=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-ppl=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-cloog=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-libelf=/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L/tmp/build/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/buildtools/lib -lpwl' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/opt/toolchains/arm-linaro-5/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-mode=thumb --with-float=hard --disable-clocale
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 20121106 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG hg+default-2af20cfd210b - arm-linaro-4)
```

And the same for `gcc-4.8.4`:

```
$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.8.4/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/work-shared/gcc-4.8.4-r0/gcc-4.8.4/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-linux --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr --bindir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi --sbindir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi --libexecdir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/arm-none-linux-gnueabi --datadir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/com --localstatedir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/var --libdir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/arm-none-linux-gnueabi --includedir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include --infodir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux --enable-clocale=generic --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --disable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- --without-local-prefix --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-ppl=no --with-cloog=no --enable-checking=release --enable-cheaders=c_global --with-gxx-include-dir=/not/exist/usr/include/c++/4.8.4 --with-sysroot=/not/exist --with-build-sysroot=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/board --enable-poison-system-directories --with-mpfr=/home/alima/projects/yocto/build/tmp-tiny/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --with-arch=armv7-a
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (GCC)
```

My questions are: Does anyone know what could be causing this? Even if you are not sure, could you please comment so I can check it?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The `(e5923008)` is  `ldr r3, [r2, #8]` and *r2==0x736563*, so it is unaligned.  However, do you have memory at 0x736563?  Normally the kernel memory is much higher.  An unaligned exception may occur because some other step resulted in corrupted memory.  For instance, it could be due to a race condition due to faster generated code, etc.  No one can answer this question here if this is the case.  A kernel mailing list is a better place to ask.

Comment: @artlessnoise thanks for that

Comment: You can use a simple `printk()` in the drivers to try and see which one is causing the issue with `device_add`; it is a platform (or OMAP specific) device.  I would then take a look at the change log from the main www.kernel.org for that driver/device.  You can find the OMAP git tree to look at a detailed history of the file.

Comment: Do you run the same configuration? ARM processor can generate interrupt on unaligned accesses, or not, depending on their configuration (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/CHDGIJFB.html). But you should rather fix the alignment issue.